# How to apply a function on a dictionary value in Python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have the below CSV, that is  a dictionary input  in Python. It is Test.csv  in this  case.

```
Cust_Id, No_of_purchases, Amount
xxx0001, 2000,3000 
xxx0002, 30 ,400
xxx0002, 20,500
```

The  below code reads it and outputs the  dictionary key as "Customer_ID" and  the rest as values.

```
with open('Test.csv', mode='r') as csv_input: 
    reader = [[x.strip() for x in rows.split(",")] for rows in csv_input.readlines()]

(customer_, *Purchases_amount), *row_values = reader 
dict_ = {}
for each_row in row_values:
    key, *values = each_row   
    dict_from_csv[key] = {key: value for key, value in zip(Purchases_amount, values)}
```

The result of printing  `dict_from_csv` is something like the below, plus the other two rows.

```
{'xxx0001': {'No_of_purchases': '2000',
  'Amount': '3000'}, .....
```

Question is: How can I apply a discount of 5 percent  if amount is  >1000 else 0 discount on the "Amount" value in the dictionary? The key is just the Cust_Id.  I have the below function to compute discount. How can I apply it to the value "Amount" in the dictionary?

```
def givediscount (value):
    dis= 0.05*value
    nodiscount = 0
    if value > 1000:
       dis = nodiscount
       break 
       nodiscount+=1
    return dis
```

Comment: `if value < value` how can the function work?

Comment: Thank you for  noticing  that. Corrected.

Comment: still cannot work.

Comment: @Hummer the issue is you were (and still are) comparing the same variable, `value`

Comment: Right @Alex. Hope that is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given discount function seems to be wrong. As per your description, this should work

```
def give_discount(amount):
    if amount > 1000:
        return amount * 0.95
    return amount
```

You can loop over the elements in the dictionary and call the function like

```
for i in dict_from_csv.keys():
    dict_from_csv[i]['Amount'] = give_discount(dict_from_csv[i]['Amount'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a function over your dictionary like so:

```py
def give_discount(row):
    amount = row.get("Amount", 0)
    if amount > 1000:
        row["discounted_amount"] = 0.95 * amount
    else:
        row["discounted_amount"] = amount
    return row

dict_from_csv = {k: give_discount(row) for k, row in dict_from_csv.items()}
```

Comment: where is `discounted_amount` from?

Comment: @LeiYang that is a new field in each sub-dictionary. It preserves the original amount